# deploying rails app first time to server capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, nginx, capistrano3

Im trying to deploy to a server with ubuntu 16.0.4 with nginx, passenger and postresql. And now when I'm deploying for the first time it all works fin until capistrano runs rake db:migrate.

```
RBENV_VERSION="2.3.3" RAILS_ENV="production" ; $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake db:migrate )
 DEBUG [c5c99ee8]   == 20160922103610 AddSignToUsers: migrating ===================================
 DEBUG [c5c99ee8]   -- add_column(:users, :sign, :string)
 DEBUG [c5c99ee8]   rake aborted!
 DEBUG [c5c99ee8]   StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
```

I understand that its because i haven't created the tables. I'm new to capistrano and wonder. Do I need to write a seperate task for this?

Heres my deploy.rb

```
# Change these
server '83.241.146.21', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{app db web}
set :repo_url,        'git@bitbucket.org:gjores/prognoser.git'
set :application,     'prognoser'


# Don't change these unless you know what you're doing
set :pty,             true
set :use_sudo,        false
set :stage,           :production
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/home/deploy/prognoser"
set :ssh_options, {:forward_agent => true}
on :start do    
  `ssh-add`
end


## Defaults:
# set :scm,           :git
# set :branch,        :master
# set :format,        :pretty
set :log_level,     :debug
set :keep_releases, 5

## Linked Files & Directories (Default None):
 set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
 set :linked_dirs,  %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}
namespace :deploy do
#   task :db_schema_load do 
#     on roles(:db) do
#       within release_path do
#         with rails_env: (fetch(:rails_env) || fetch(:stage)) do
#           execute :rake, 'db:schema:load'
#         end
#       end
#     end
#   end

# end
# namespace :deploy do
#   desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
#   task :check_revision do
#     on roles(:app) do
#       unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
#         puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
#         puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
#         exit
#       end
#     end
#   end

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

#   desc 'Restart application'
#   task :restart do
#     on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
#       invoke 'puma:restart'
#     end
#   end

#   before :starting,     :check_revision
#   after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
#   after  :finishing,    :cleanup
#   after  :finishing,    :restart
 end

# ps aux | grep puma    # Get puma pid
# kill -s SIGUSR2 pid   # Restart puma
# kill -s SIGTERM pid   # Stop puma
```

And here is my capfile

```
# Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/scm/git'
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require 'capistrano/passenger'
require 'capistrano/postgresql'

set :rbenv_type, :user
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.3.3'
# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
# If you are using rvm add these lines:
# require 'capistrano/rvm'
```

Comment: capistano works correctly, problem is with your migrations files

Comment: Can you not just SSH to the production VM and manually run `rake db:create` to initialise it? Or maybe there's an issue with your migrations, and you're saying "add column to table" without first saying "create table".

Comment: create table users not exist in your migration which causes error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to load schema with command:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:schema:load
```

Comment: Shall i try this as a task? Or just SSH to host and do it there?

Comment: ssh and run there directly

Comment: But the app isn't deployd yet so there is nothing in the app directory yet. Feel like the chicken and the egg. ;)

Comment: create repo on github and push all code then pull code on server by ssh..simple